# R distance to specific points

Tags: r, matrix, grouping, distance

please consider following (simplified matrix).

```
x1  <- c(2,2,2,3,1,2,4,6,1,2,4)
y1  <- c(5,4,3,3,4,2,1,6,4,2,3)
x2  <- c(8,2,7,3,1,2,2,2,1,2,6)
y2  <- c(1,3,3,3,1,2,4,3,1,2,8)
x3  <- c(4,4,1,2,4,6,3,2,4,6,9)
y3  <- c(1,2,3,3,1,2,4,6,1,2,1)
x4  <- c(4,4,1,2,4,6,3,2,4,6,9)
y4  <- c(1,2,3,3,1,2,4,6,1,2,1)
x5  <- c(4,1,2,4,6,2,3,3,6,2,9)
y5  <- c(1,3,3,3,1,2,4,6,1,2,1)
ID  <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
id1 <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b")
id2 <- c("f","f","g","h","h","i","j","k","k","k","l")
dat <- data.frame(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,id1, id2)
```

What I want to achieve is to get the average distance between each id2 to all other ids (which is NOT id2) per group of id1's.

I started with

```
matrix_split <- split(dat, dat$id1)
```

This gets me split matrices, in this simplified example 2. I can easily create distance matrices that then show the mean distance to each group member:

```
dist <- lapply(matrix_split, function(x) dist(x, diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))
dist2 <- lapply(dist, as.matrix)
mean <- lapply(dist2, rowMeans)
```

Now, my question is how I can find the average distance to ONLY over groups for each row. That is, of this distance matrices, I would only count those to the rowMeans function that are not element of the same id2.

For instance, for ID=1, which is in the "f" group, the ID2 should not be counted for the rowMeans. Is there any way to doing so? This example is simplified and there are about 400 matrices, so an operationalization that does not contain code for each single matrix would be good.

So instead of 
dist2$a

```
ID       1        2        3        4

1 0.000000 7.483315 5.416026 7.483315

2 7.483315 0.000000 6.928203 3.265986
3 5.416026 6.928203 0.000000 4.898979
4 7.483315 3.265986 4.898979 0.000000
```

This would be great!

```
ID       1        2        3        4

1 0.000000 NA       5.416026 7.483315
2 NA       0.000000 6.928203 3.265986
3 5.416026 6.928203 0.000000 4.898979
4 7.483315 3.265986 4.898979 0.000000
```

From there I would go ahead with rowMeans again :

```
1 4.29978
2 3.398063
3 .... 
4 ....
```

and could perhaps solve the problem. Any suggestions? Thanks already now!! Tobi

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Would this `lapply(matrix_split, function(x) lapply(x$id2, function(i) rowMeans(as.matrix(dist(x[i!=x$id2,-c(7:8)])))))` work for you?

Comment: @Akrun, looks nearly good! Hmm, I calculated one row and it is different however.

Comment: Do you get warnings for `lapply(matrix_split, function(x) dist(x, diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))`?  I guess it should be `lapply(matrix_split, function(x) dist(x[,-(7:8)], diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))`.  also, I am not completely sure what your expected answer might be.

Comment: @Akrun, i get warnings as well, yes - what does the 7:8 stand for? Hmm, I calculated one row and it is different however. The rowMeans should be the means of the distances already, e.g., from $b[[1]] to $b[[6]] it should be sqrt((1-2)^2 + ...). To all these distances there should be applied the rowSums then (within the group and only for the values that are different in terms of id2. Not sure what is wroign with the code, but the rowMeans should go after calculating these distances. Hope this helps, I am also trying to recode your suggestion (which looks really good already).

Comment: Put differently: given that id2 indicates people from one state, and id1 indicates the countries, I only want to look how each subject from one state differs in terms of the euclidean distances by all the variables from all subjects of OTHER STATES in this one country. If I know for instance that the subject x differs from subject y,z (which do not belong to the same state but to the same country) for 5 and 7, then the average distance would be 6 for subject x. Essentially each subject should have one mean difference value only at the end.

Comment: But these matrices are of different dimensions `$b[[1]] to $b[[6]]

Comment: You may need to look at `library(proxy)` for dist between two groups.  `lapply(matrix_split, function(x) lapply(x$id2, function(i) {x1 <-x[i!=x$id2, -(7:8)]; x2 <- x[i==x$id2,-(7:8)] }))`.  Here the two groups are `x1` and `x2`

Comment: Yes, hmm, let's say, the solution should be exact the same as I indicated, but just that those distances count, that are from a different id2. Not sure how to put that differently. In the example, I illustrated that for the first matrix. Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: May be somebody else understand the problem better

Comment: actually, this: lapply(matrix_split, function(x) lapply(x$id2, function(i) as.matrix(dist(x[i!=x$id2,-c(7:8)]))))
is very close, but it calculates only distance matrices between the other elements and not from the first element TO the others